# Problem with using wildcards when I do CP command in Terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, cp, wildcards

I am new and try to learning Terminal Command. Today I faced some problem with cp wildcard command option. I wrote in Terminal this command

```
cp Downloads/[:alnum:]  test/
```

Here, `Downloads` is the directory from where I want to copy alphanumeric character file to my `test` directory. But When I ran this command showed me:

```
cannot stat ‘Downloads/[:alnum:]’: No such file or directory
```

I want to know, how I can use above Wildcard Classes for `cp` command. And Also how I can use above Wildcard Character command.

Wildcards are

```
 * 
? 
[characters]
[!characters]
[[:classes:]]
```

Commonly used classes are

```
[:alnum:]-> Match any Alphanumeric Character
[:alpha:] -> Match any Alphabetic Character
[:digit:] -> Match any nummeral 
[:lower:] -> Matches any lowercase letter
[:upper:] -> Matches any Uppercase letter
```

How can I use those Wildcard and its Classes?

Answer (score 3):

`cp` does not support any wildcards by itself. Expansion of wildcards and patterns is done by the shell, which is `bash` by default.

In any case, character classes are to be specified within `[]` - that excludes the `[]` already surrounding them. Like so:

```
cp Downloads/[[:alnum:]] test/
```

However, `[[:alnum:]]` will only match a single alphanumeric character. To match all filenames containing only alphanumeric characters can't be done with just the wildcards already listed. For more powerful filtering, look into the `find` command:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*/[[:alnum:]]*'
```

Within `bash`, you can use [extended globs](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language):

```
shopt -s extglob
cp Downloads/*([[:alnum:]]) test/
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention that one can use `-exec` flag to call cp per each file

Answer (score 2):

`[:alnum:]` actually matches a single character *from the set* `:`, `a`, `l`, `n`, `u`, `m` i.e. given

```
$ ls
_?_  123  7  a  abc  :file  fi:le  m
```

then

```
$ ls [:alnum:]
a  m
```

To match a single character from the alphanumeric *class* `[:alnum:]` it needs to be `[[:alnum:]]`

```
$ ls [[:alnum:]]
7  a  m
```

To match a single alphanumeric character followed by zero or more arbitrary characters

```
$ ls [[:alnum:]]*
123  7  a  abc  fi:le  m
```

To match file consisting *only* of alphanumeric characters using shell globbing requires *extended glob* (`extglob`) syntax

```
$ ls +([[:alnum:]])
123  7  a  abc  m
```